# German characters in angularJS live search

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

German characters in AngularJS live search

I have problem with AngularJS live search from MySQL, everything works perfectly except German characters. I tried everything but without results.

This is my JS code:

```
PATH = 'search.php';

var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
   //live search controller for welcome view and welcome controller
    app.controller('SearchController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.url = 'search.php'; // the get request page
    $scope.search = function (){
        //create the http post request
        //the data holds the search key
        //the request is a json request
        $http.post($scope.url,
        {"data":$scope.keybords}
                ).success(function (data, status){
                    $scope.status = status;
                    $scope.data = data;
                    $scope.result = data;
                }).error(function (data, status){
                    $scope.data = data || "Request Failed";
                    $scope.status = status;
                });
    };
});
```

This is my PHP code:

```
    <?php
 mysql_set_charset('utf8');
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once './db_connect.php';

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

            $objData = json_decode($data);

            $key =  $objData->data;
            if(!empty($key)){

                $sql = "SELECT * from search where title LIKE '%$key%' or description LIKE '%$key%' OR url LIKE '%$key%'";

                $result =   mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

                $output = array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $output[] = $row;

                }
                echo json_encode($output);
            }


?>
```

...and here is testpage:
http://www.topfertighaus.at/ng_live_search/index.html

Comment: Those problems are not easy to debug. The first thing you should check if the data is _valid_  after `json_decode`. So send a request  `{data: "ä"}` and in php check if  `$objData->data == "ä"` (you need to make sure that you edit your php document with _utf-8 without BOM_). If this works then check if hardcoding `$key='ä';`  will give you a result from mysql.

Comment: Beside that don't insert values without escaping to your mysql query. This can be used for SQL injections. Especially because you published a live link to your vulnerable code.

Comment: Tnx, but this doesn't work.

Comment: `[...]but this doesn't work[...]` does not explain much. I told you that you should first check if `$objData->data == "ä"`  when searching for `ä`.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i tried and seem  have found something but does not show description with ä character, except link to description.

Comment: You comments are still not helpfull. Is `$objData->data == "ä"`  ???? `[...]something but does not show description with ä character, except link to description.[...]`  What is _something_, `does not show description with ä character` does it show the right description, but the special chars like `ä` are not displayed correctly? `except link to description`  what link to what description?

Comment: Displayed nothing with 'ä' just url link to the description where it 'ä' appears .